# Considerations for transitioning from a teaching to a pure research position

Tags: research-process, teaching, job

Understandably, there would be some adjustment needed, particularly if the academic had been in the predominantly teaching role for a long time (or it is the only academic role they've had).

What practical considerations are there that would help an academic currently fulfilling a primarily teaching position to seamlessly and effectively transition to being in an all-research position (any job that is all research, no teaching)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "pure" research position?

Comment: @aeismail pure research in this case, refers to no teaching, just research.

Comment: So, are you talking about non-academic positions (for example, research in government labs), or academic positions (e.g., research assistant professor)?

Comment: When you talking about practical considerations to help in transitioning from a teaching to a research position, do you mean to help in getting a research job, or help in handling the transition once you've accepted the job?

Comment: @aeismail any research job that has no teaching component.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I mean help handling the transition once the job is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues that will need to be considered are:

- getting up to date with the current developments in your field – this will involve intense and selective reading
- finding new topics to work on
- justifying in grant applications the gap in publication record and demonstrating potential to produce results
- attracting students to work with you – this may be easier if you've been teaching a lot, as you've put yourself in a position where students can see you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Dave, this is the succinct and helpful information I am after.